# Nested loop to generate unique id variables

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to have the following output for Yrst:

```
Y111 + Y112 + Y113 + Y211 + Y212 + Y213 + Y311 + Y312 + Y313
```

I have the following code:

```
r=1
s=1
t=1
for a in r:
    while r <= 3:
        r+1
        for b in s:
            while s <= 3:
                s+1
                for c in t:
                    while t <= 3:
                        t+1
                        print("Y",r,"Y",s,"Y",t)
```

I am getting confused with all these nested loops. I also do not know how to add those "+" signs.

Error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: for all Y r and s and t? similar output. is it?

Comment: rst are subscripts if you actually put it on paper. Yes, 111, 112, etc. represents rst. The output is what I have there.

Comment: `r` is an `int` it can't iterate,

Comment: @Bijoy yes I am sorry I forgot to put in the error, and this is it. However, that is not my problem. I know my code is wrong. I need help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r` is an integer,so it isn't **iterable**.

Try this:

```
from itertools import product

num = "".join(map(str, range(1, 4)))
l = map(lambda x: 'Y' + x, (map('1'.join, product(num, num))))

print("+".join(l))
```

Output:

```
Y111+Y112+Y113+Y211+Y212+Y213+Y311+Y312+Y313
```

Comment: I want it to display exactly like what I have with + signs. No commas or anything else whatsoever and no parentheses either.

Comment: @Ted111 use `"+".join(output)`

Comment: @McGrady  Added the edit to match the questions output!!

Comment: He's using python2, you're probably on python3.

Comment: Got it now. that helped.

Comment: Now in McGrady's solution, what if I want to go over 9 meaning Y919, then I have an idea of doing 001001001, where the first three digits represent r, second three s, and third three t. How can I do that?

Comment: Yes McGrady you are absolutely correct, but I posted the sample output. The variables I have actually 32, so what I suggested Ng Oon-Ee is what I would like. I can't have Y323232. So, it would be best to have 032032032, and for 111, 001001001.

Comment: Anyone help please?

Comment: @Ted111 Sure,nested loop can generate custom results.And it is easier to understand,I suggest you read [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and other [functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), try them several times,try to read the Python wiki and debug your code.Before you ask question,please make sure what output is you want.

Comment: Please help me McGrady. I didn't realize that until I ran your given code. I mean I was worried about my code being wrong, so I didn't even think that far.

Comment: @Ted111 StackOverflow is not a  coding, or tutorial service. It helps you fix code issue,and on the other hand,you should try to read document.That helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@McGrady has already done the pythonic way, so something which answers the other part of your question (what's wrong with your code):-

```
output = []
for r in range(1, 4):
    for s in range(1, 4):
        for t in range(1,4):
            output.append("Y" + str(r) + str(s) + str(t))
print(" + ".join(output)
```

Comment: If I go over 9, then 111 repeats which would be incorrect. The only solution to that which is what I would like now is to have 111 as 001001001, and so on. How would I do that?

Comment: And your code is giving me `Y111 + Y112 + Y113 + Y121 + Y122 + Y123 + Y131 + Y132 + Y133 + Y211 + Y212 + Y213 + Y221 + Y222 + Y223 + Y231 + Y232 + Y233 + Y311 + Y312 + Y313 + Y321 + Y322 + Y323 + Y331 + Y332 + Y333`

Comment: As you've already been told, you really need to read up more on python. You've posted a question which does not fully describe what you're trying to achieve, and you don't seem to understand simple string processing. Basically, you need to do your homework rather than asking repeatedly.